# compare two arrays Laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, filter, compare

I have articles that can contain different tags. For example, 5 pieces: (php, html, css, laravel, js) And I have groups that can also contain different tags. For example 4 pieces: (laravel, php, html, css)

I have already defined the relationships and it works. What I still lack is the linkage of article to the group.

In the Articlecontroller i use this so sync:

```
$article->groups()->sync($group->id);
```

Article Model

```
  public function groups()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group');
  }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Tag', 'taggable');
    }
```

Tag Model

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Article', 'taggable');
}

public function groups()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Group', 'taggable');
}
```

Group Model

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Tag', 'taggable');
}

public function articles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Article');
}
```

Controller

```
$groups = $user->groups()->latest()->with('tags')->paginate(20);
$mostvotedarticle = Article::where('type', 4)->whereIn('privacy', [1, 3])->orderByVotes()->first(); //show only article with the same tags
$imagearticle = Article::with('comments')->whereIn('type', [4, 5])->where('status', 1)->latest()->paginate(30); //show only articles with the same tags
```

I would now like to compare the tags of the groups and the tags of the posts. If the posts have the same tags as the group, I want to display the posts.

Comment: when you say posts are you referring to articles?

Comment: In the taggable table

Answer (score 0):

simply check for equality

```
$equal = ($tagsFromPost == $tagsFromGroup) //TRUE if both have the same values but NOT in order
$equal = ($tagsFromPost === $tagsFromGroup) //TRUE if both have same values in SAME order
```

then something like

```
if($equal){
    <statements>
}
```

to check for FALSE `if(!$equal)...`

Comment: how can i load the matching article with your code?