# Load tags from taggables

Tags: laravel, tags, polymorphism, load

I would like to display the 4 most used tags of the last 4 hours with this code:

```
$topTags = Taggable::whereDate('created_at', '>=', now()->subHours(4))
    ->groupBy('tag_id')
    ->orderByRaw('count(tag_id) DESC'))
    ->take(4)
    ->with('tags')
    ->get();
```

Tables

```
Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

 Schema::create('taggables', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('tag_id');
            $table->integer('taggable_id');
            $table->string('taggable_type');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

What relationship do I need between tag table and taggables? How can I access the tag name in the view? If i use the belongsTo relation:

```
class Taggable extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['tag_id', 'taggable_id', 'taggable_type'];

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Tag');
    }
}
```

the tag array is empty:

```
 #relations: array:1 [▼
        "tags" => null
      ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially I suggest the tags() relation name of the Taggable entity should be only tag().

Then the Taggable entity should have own "id" like this:

```
 Schema::create('taggables', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('tag_id');
            $table->integer('taggable_id');
            $table->string('taggable_type');
            $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Lastly the Taggable entity should have an polymorphic relation like this:

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo
 */
public function taggable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}

public function tag()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Tag');
}
```

So you can access the tag name with just like this:

```
$topTags = Taggable::whereDate('created_at', '>=', now()->subHours(4))
    ->groupBy('tag_id')
    ->orderByRaw('count(tag_id) DESC'))
    ->take(4)
    ->with('tag')
    ->get();

foreach($topTags as $ttag){
    $ttag->tag->name;
}
```

Don't forget to add to other entities which related with Taggable:

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\morphMany
 */
public function taggables()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Taggable::class, 'taggable');
}
```

Usage of the Taggable relation like this:

```
    $anyOtherModel->taggables()->create([
        'tag_id'     => $tag->id,
    ]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have another problem, maybe you would like to have a look:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52347942/compare-two-arrays-laravel/52349883#52349883